# Visual Studio IntelliSense & syntax highlighting not recognizing Unity types

Tags: unity, visual-studio

Frequently when I open a Unity C# script in Visual Studio, the built-in Unity Engine types aren't recognized, so I don't get syntax highlighting or code completion hints for things like `MonoBehaviour`.

[image: VS screenshot showing MonoBehaviour without syntax highlighting]

Sometimes if I delete the script and create a new one it works, but lately nothing I do solves the problem.  Is there something I can do?

Comment: Doesn't sync? What does that mean?

Comment: Same thing happens to me too. Intellisense doesn't recognize what MonoBehaviour is until I restart VS. idk how to fix it

Comment: @DMGregory He asked the question on Sep 30, while the "duplicate" question was asked on Nov 3, why is THIS question marked as duplicate and not the other?!?!

Comment: The other question has answers, so it makes sense to direct users from a question with no answers to one with. Closing as a duplicate isn't a judgment or punishment against a question, just a way of centralising the information so it's easy for everyone to find, and rate the best available answers in one place.